# Python asn.1 DER encoding Sequence NamedTypes can cast only scalar values

Tags: python, asn.1, der

I am trying to build a ASN.1 type containing a variable size list of integers and tried it like this

```
class ASNBigInteger(Integer):
    """
    A subtype of the pyasn1 Integer type to support
    bigger numbers
    """
    subtypeSpec = ValueRangeConstraint(0x1, 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141)

class ANSBigIntegerList(univ.SequenceOf):
    """
    A subytpe of Sequenceof for variable length
    list of BigIntegers
    """
    componentType = ASNBigInteger()
    subtypeSpec = ValueSizeConstraint(1, 9223372036854775807)

class ASNMLSAGSignature(Sequence):
    """
    ASN.1 type specification for MLSAG
    Ring Signature
    """
    componentType = NamedTypes(
        NamedType('Ix', ASNBigInteger()),
        NamedType('Iy', ASNBigInteger()),
        NamedType('c0', ASNBigInteger()),
        NamedType('sl', ANSBigIntegerList())
    )
```

Trying to use this type like:

```
def get_asn1_encoded(self) -> str:
    """
    Get the ring signature as der encoded
    :return: asn encoded signature
    """
    asn = ASNMLSAGSignature()
    asn["Ix"] = self.I().x()
    asn["Iy"] = self.I().y()
    asn["c0"] = self.c0()
    asn["sl"] = self.sl()
    serialized = encode(asn)
    return serialized.hex()
```

(Notice that self.sl() returns a list of integers)
On the line where I am setting the sl value I get this error:

```
KeyError: PyAsn1Error('NamedTypes can cast only scalar values',)
```

Is there a different way how I need cast the python list into the ASN.1 list or is there something wrong with my type definition?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by changing the list type to: (removing the unnecessary constraint)

```
class ANSIntegerList(univ.SequenceOf):
    """
    A subytpe of Sequenceof for variable length
    list of BigIntegers
    """
    componentType = ASNBigInteger()
```

and the encoding part to: (Creating the list object and adding the values using extend function)

```
def get_asn1_encoded(self) -> str:
    """
    Get the ring signature as der encoded
    :return: asn encoded signature
    """
    asn = ASNMLSAGSignature()
    asn["Ix"] = self.I().x()
    asn["Iy"] = self.I().y()
    asn["c0"] = self.c0()
    asnlist = ANSIntegerList()
    asnlist.extend(self.sl())
    asn["sl"] = asnlist
    serialized = encode(asn)
    return serialized.hex()
```